# undefined symbol: lua_rotate

Tags: nginx, lua, cjson

I had done below steps,
downloaded lua-cjson-2.1.0.7 from this repo, Not really know what went wrong. can anybody know whats going on and how to resolve this?

```
make install
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1
rm -f /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cjson.so
cp cjson.so /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1
chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cjson.so
```

Then,

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Error:

```
2020/02/19 06:59:52 [error] 29524#29524: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: error loading module 'cjson' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cjson.so':
        /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cjson.so: undefined symbol: lua_rotate
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
        [C]: in function 'require'
```

**nginx.conf has below :**

lua_package_path "/usr/local/lib/lua/?.lua;;";

And

```
/usr/bin/lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Comment: Function `lua_rotate` exists only in Lua 5.3+.  Probably you should say somehow to cjson that you want to build a library for Lua 5.1

Comment: How can i do that?